# Create a load process

Tags: r

Having commands like this one

```
gsub("\\s[A-Za-z](?= )", "", "I am a text r r o n n r and here", perl = TRUE)
```

as it takes sometime to execute is it possible to have a line which shows the percantage level that the process is remain until to end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `pbapply`.

```
library("pbapply")

x <- replicate(1e4, "I am a text r r o n n r and here")  # generate 10,000 example strings

res <- pbapply(as.matrix(x), 1, function(x) gsub("\\s[A-Za-z](?= )", "", x, perl=TRUE))
# |++++++++++++++++++++++++++++                      | 55% ~01s
```

Access results:

```
res[1]
# [1] "I am text and here" 
res[2]
...
```